# Finding a counterexample of approximating the solution to $x'=f(x,t)$ by $x_{n+1}'=f(x_n,t)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

Suppose we have a Cauchy problem

$$x'=f(x(t),t),\quad x(t_0)=C,$$

where $f$ is Lipschitz continuous in its first argument and continuous in its second argument.
By Picard theorem, there must exist a unique solution within some interval $t\in[t_0-\varepsilon,t_0+\varepsilon]$.
Now, on this interval, construct a sequence of functions $(x_n)$ by recursive formula

$$x_0(t):=C,\quad x_{n+1}(t):=\int_{t_0}^tf(x_n(s),s)\,\mathrm ds+C.$$

It is clear that $x_{n+1}'(t)=f(x_n(t),t)$,
and if we take the limit $n\to\infty$,
we can see $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ is the solution to the original ODE
if the sequence $(x_n')$ **converges uniformly** on the interval we consider.

Because of the uniform convergence condition, we can potentially get a wrong solution by this procedure.
Is it guaranteed that $\lim x_n$ exists?
Can we construct $f$ and $C$ such that $(x_n')$ fails to converge uniformly, and $\lim x_n$ exists but is a wrong solution?
If we cannot, then is it guaranteed that $\lim x_n$ is a solution as long as it exists?
Can we find the sufficient and necessary condition for $\lim x_n$ to exist and be the solution?

Comment: The sequence converges uniformly. One proof of [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#:~:text=A%20simple%20proof%20of%20existence,is%20known%20as%20Picard%20iteration.&text=It%20can%20then%20be%20shown,a%20solution%20to%20the%20problem.) proves that inside the proof itself. See [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Introduction_to_Real_Analysis_(Lebl)/08%3A_Metric_Spaces/8.06%3A_Fixed_point_theorem_and_Picard%E2%80%99s_theorem_again) for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hypothesis of [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) are sufficient to ensure that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges uniformly. See [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Introduction_to_Real_Analysis_(Lebl)/08%3A_Metric_Spaces/8.06%3A_Fixed_point_theorem_and_Picard%E2%80%99s_theorem_again) for a proof of Picard–Lindelöf theorem that proves this uniform convergence as a by-product.